# Firebase realtime database validate child object in array

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to validate that an array value only contains certain elements.

The "focus" key, should only contain any or both of the following: "movement", "strength".

So I tried sending this:

```
{
  "focus": ["movement"]
}
```

... and the security rules:

```
 "$id": {
    "focus" : {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChild('movement') || newData.hasChild('strength') || newData.hasChildren(['strength', 'movement'])"
    }
}
```

But get "Simulated update denied" and cannot understand why.

Thanks in advance